# Данные в select'e не отображаются

Tags: c#

Подскажите, делаю запрос к AD и через консоль вижу все данные, но если пытаюсь добавить в select, то пишет ошибка, где я накосячил с кодом? Может есть проще и лучше код. Прошу не судить строго, только учусь, заранее благодарен.

```
List<string> adlist = new List<string>();

 using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "domain.ru"))
 {
   using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
         {
           foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                   {
                     DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                     var lastname = (de.Properties["sn"].Value != null) ? de.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString() : "";
                     var display = (de.Properties["displayName"].Value != null) ? de.Properties["displayName"].Value.ToString() : "";
                            if (lastname != "")
                                {
                                    adlist.Add(display);
                                    adlist.Distinct().ToArray();
                                }
                        }
                    ADUserList.DataSource = adlist;
                    ADUserList.DataBind();
                    }
                }

<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control selectpicker" ID="ADUserList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

> [DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x80072020): An operations error
>   occurred. ]    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean
>   throwIfFail) +563130    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>   +45    System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject() +40    System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection.PopulateList() +27
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection..ctor(DirectoryEntry
>   entry, String propertyName) +119
>   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection.get_Item(String
>   propertyName) +162
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoLDAPDirectoryInitNoContainer()
>   +1400    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoDomainInit()
>   +47    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.Initialize()
>   +123    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.get_QueryCtx()
>   +40    System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher.SetDefaultPageSizeForContext()
>   +31    OrgChart.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.GetActiveDirectory()
>   +245    OrgChart.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +4108    System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) +106    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
>   System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
>   +11898100    OrgChart.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1.CreateChildControls() +152
>   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +106
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +66
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +256
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +6875

Comment: Запустите под отладкой и посмотрите конкретную ошибку

Comment: Ну вот примерно так.

Comment: Скорее всего апп пулл в IIS запущен под юзером, у которого нет доступа в AD (под каким-нибудь локальным ApplicationPoolItentity). Попробуйте поменять на Network Service.

Comment: Не совсем логично, в console app же не отваливается.

Comment: Ну да, консоль работает под вами (под доменным пользователем). А asp.net работает под урезанным пользователем по умолчанию. Поэтому там отваливается, а в консоли - работает.

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать. А вы не в курсе какие права нужно расширить для доменной УЗ?

Comment: Честно - не знаю, не работал с этим настолько плотно :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для **доменной** учетной записи **чтение** из AD без ограничений по-умолчанию. Для любой локальной учетной записи, в том числе и той, под которой работает IIS, ни какие права не помогут. Локальная учетная запись в AD доступ не получит. Можете попробовать запустить консольное приложение от имени любой локальной учетной записи и получите похожий результат - исключение в связи с отсутствием прав.

Варианты есть:

1. В IIS создать отдельный пул для приложения и настроить его на запуск от имени доменной учетной записи, вообще говоря любой, но обязательно доменной. Учетную запись для этого стоит специально создать в AD, запретить интерактивный вход в систему и включить во все, необходимые для IIS локальные группы безопасности сервера, чтобы приложение корректно работало. Хороший вариант в плане безопасности, но требует некоторых знаний администрирования IIS и не позволяет понять какой реальный пользователь выполняет запрос в AD если, конечно, это критично для приложения.

   Можно попробовать использовать учетную запись local system для пула, но это плохой вариант в плане безопасности, т.к. ваше приложение получит ничем неограниченный доступ ко всем ресурсам сервера без исключений.
2. Указать доменные учетные данные в конструкторе `PrincipalContext`, у него есть соответствующая перегрузка. Только не надо зашивать учетные данные в код, вынесите, хотя бы, в конфиг, а в идеале запросить у пользователя. Самый простой, но и самый небезопасный вариант.
3. Если приложение поддерживает windows-авторизацию - использовать олицетворение ASP.NET. В плане безопасности все хорошо, но работает только для доменных пользователей приложения и также требует некоторых знаний администрирования IIS.

В общем-то на этом варианты похоже кончились, во всяком случае я ничего больше припомнить не могу. Читать AD могут только доменные пользователи и это не обходится. Поместить локального пользователя в группу безопасности домена не поможет.

Comment: Спасибо, буду рассматривать все что вы написали :)